# Вывести значение Value с объекта в Alert();

Tags: javascript, html, json

Интересует вопрос, как можно реализовать вывод конкретных данных с объекта через JavaScript Vanilla? Есть ли какие-либо способы парсинга данных значений? Пробовала найти библиотеки, но ничего подходящего не нашла. Спасибо.

[image: Изображение - Схема]

Результат (нарисовала для примера):

[image: Результат]

Comment: Через "точки"... `let bubu = amdocsDigitalStore.servicability.serviceabilityAdress; alert( bubu.stateOrProvince + '\n' + bubu.street + '\n' + bubu.streetNuber );` У вас там в одном месте servicability, в другом servic`e`ability - потенциальная ошибка.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Выдает ошибку: Uncaught ReferenceError: amdocsDigitalStore is not defined at <anonymous>:1:12. То есть через консоль не видит данного объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню немного ответ от `OPTIMUS PRIME`

Данная ошибка "`Выдает ошибку: Uncaught ReferenceError: amdocsDigitalStore is not defined at <anonymous>:1:12`", просто из-за того что amdocsDigitalStore это не переменная локальная или глобальная, а ключ из `sessionStorage`

```
const bubu = sessionStorage.amdocsDigitalStore.servicability.serviceabilityAddress;

alert( bubu.stateOrProvince + '\n' + bubu.street + '\n' + bubu.streetNuber );
```

Вот так по идее должно работать.

UPD: спасибо за уточнение, ваш сайт в sessionStorage.amdocsDigitalStore хранит JSON в виде строки, вам нужно сделать JSON.parse:

```
const bubu = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.amdocsDigitalStore).servicability.serviceabilityAddress;

alert( bubu.stateOrProvince + '\n' + bubu.street + '\n' + bubu.streetNuber );
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, попробывала, как вы написали, выдает "Cannot read property 'serviceabilityAddress' of undefined".

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/2NJc3vf/Screen-Shot-2019-09-05-at-00-12-35.png

Comment: @IsabellaMonza обновил ответ, попробуйте, была проблема что в слове address была одна d

Comment: я заметила и исправила, результат тот же.

Comment: можете прислать сюда исходный JSON?

Comment: @IsabellaMonza обновил ответ

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо большое за помощь! Буду глубже изучать эту тему.

Comment: да не за что:))